# Como adaptar para que todos os itens <li> puxem uma div diferente?

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, tenho o seguinte código:

```
<ul class="t_situacoes">
<?

if(isset($row)){
    $row_pedido = $row;
}

if (!isset($situacoes_andamento))
    $situacoes_andamento=$row_pedido->situacoes;

foreach($situacoes_andamento as $situacao){
    if(in_array($situacao->id_situacao, $situacoes_layout)){
        ?>
        <li class="situacao-<?=$situacoes_layout_classes[$situacao->id_situacao];?> <?=$row_pedido->id_situacao == $situacao->id_situacao ? 'atual' : ''?>">
            <span></span>
            <?=$situacao->nome_situacao;?>
            <div id="botao-mais-detalhes" class="show-hidden-menu-<?=$situacoes_layout_classes[$situacao->id_situacao];?>" style="text-transform: lowercase;">&#709; mais detalhes</div>

        </li>
        <div id="box-mais-detalhes" class="hidden-menu-<?=$situacoes_layout_classes[$situacao->id_situacao];?>" style="display: none;">
            <div id="seta"></div>
            <p id="texto-mais-detalhes">
                <?=$situacao->nome_situacao;?>
                <small>em <?=$ecommerce->getDate($situacao->data);?> &agrave;s <?=$situacao->hora;?></small>
                <em><?=$situacao->observacao_loja;?></em>
            </p>
        </div>

<?  }
} ?>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.show-hidden-menu-<?=$situacoes_layout_classes[$situacao->id_situacao];?>').click(function() {
            $('.hidden-menu-<?=$situacoes_layout_classes[$situacao->id_situacao];?>').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Acontece que a ação da div 'mais detalhes' só funciona no último item

gerado. 
Alguém pode me explicar onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vai dar errado mesmo porque o script está fora do laço e o último valor de `<?=$situacoes_layout_classes[$situacao->id_situacao];?>` só vai pegar a última div relacionada.

> Note também que você está repetindo as id's `id="texto-mais-detalhes"`,
>   `id="seta"` e `id="botao-mais-detalhes"` dentro do laço. Não é correto repetir a mesma id em mais
>   de um elemento na mesma página. Se essas id's não servem pra nada,
>   você deve removê-las ou então usar como `class`.

Pra resolver seu problema, você não precisa usar nenhum tipo de identificação que relacione um elemento ao outro. Você pode usar métodos do jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.show-hidden-menu').click(function(){
      $(this)  // div clicada
      .closest('li')  // busca a <li> onde está a div
      .next()  // busca o próximo elemento, que é a div a ser mostrada
      .slideToggle("slow");  // faz o slide
   });
});
```

A div a ser clicada ficaria apenas assim, sem `id` e sem o código PHP:

```
<div class="show-hidden-menu" style="text-transform: lowercase;">&#709; mais detalhes</div>
```

Bem como você deve retirar os outros id's repetidos e os códigos PHP que está adicionando nas classes.

**No entanto**, segundo as especificações **[HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)**, você não pode usar uma div como filho direto de uma `ul`. Você teria que colocar cada div dentro de cada `li`, logo após a div a ser clicada. Daí mudaria o código jQuery para abrir:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.show-hidden-menu').click(function(){
      $(this)  // div clicada
      .next()  // busca o próximo elemento, que é a div a ser mostrada
      .slideToggle("slow");  // faz o slide
   });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução e pelas dicas!!!